# Using Profiles with nestjsx-automapper in nest.js

Tags: node.js, mapping, automapper, nestjs

I´m using **nestjsx-automapper** (https://automapper.netlify.app/docs/usages/init/add-profile) by Chau Tran (thanks for that cool piece of code). I´ve implemented it like shown in the documentation and as already discussed here:
[How use profiles from nartc/automapper into a nestjs application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61429313/how-use-profiles-from-nartc-automapper-into-a-nestjs-application)

But I still have a **problem to access AutoMapper from within my Profile** class.

Here´s my setup:

**app.module.ts:**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { MerchantModule } from './merchant/merchant.module';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { AutomapperModule, AutoMapper } from 'nestjsx-automapper';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      ...
    }),
    AutomapperModule.withMapper(),
    MerchantModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  controllers: [],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**merchant.module.ts:**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MerchantController } from './merchant.controller';
import { MerchantService } from './merchant.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Merchant } from './entities/merchant.entity';
import { MerchantProfile } from './profiles/merchant.profile';
import { AutoMapper, AutomapperModule } from 'nestjsx-automapper';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Merchant]), AutomapperModule, MerchantProfile],
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
  controllers: [MerchantController],
  providers: [MerchantService]
})
export class MerchantModule {}
```

**merchant.profile.ts:**

```js
import {
  ProfileBase,
  Profile,
  AutoMapper
} from 'nestjsx-automapper';
import { Merchant } from '../entities/merchant.entity';
import { MerchantDto } from '../dto/merchant.dto';

@Profile()
export class MerchantProfile extends ProfileBase {
  constructor(
    private readonly mapper: AutoMapper) {
    super();
    mapper.createMap(Merchant, MerchantDto);
  }

    configure(): void {      
      return null;
    }
}
```

merchant.controller.ts:

```js
import { Controller, Get, Param, Post, Body, Put, Delete } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MerchantService } from './merchant.service';
import { Merchant } from './entities/merchant.entity';
import { MerchantDto } from './dto/merchant.dto';
import { DeleteResult } from 'typeorm';
import { AutoMapper, InjectMapper } from 'nestjsx-automapper';

@Controller('merchant')
export class MerchantController {

    constructor(
        private merchantService: MerchantService,
        @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: AutoMapper) { }

    @Get()
    public async findAll(): Promise<MerchantDto[]> {
        return this.mapper.mapArray(await this.merchantService.find(),MerchantDto);
    }
}
```

When I run the application with this setup I get the following exception:
**Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AutomapperModule (?). Please make sure that the argument AutomapperExplorer at index [0] is available in the AutomapperModule context.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AutoMapperModule.withMapper()` in `AppModule` is the only time you'd need to use `AutoMapperModule`.

`withMapper()` creates a singleton of `AutoMapper` that will be available via `@InjectMapper()` when you want to use the `Mapper` in a `Service` (or any `Injectable`).

As for `Profile`, the following is the correct syntax:

```js
@Profile()
export class MerchantProfile extends ProfileBase {
  constructor(mapper: AutoMapper) { // no private readonly.
    super();
    mapper.createMap(Merchant, MerchantDto);
  }
  // no configure() method
}
```

The following is the `@nartc/automapper` source code where `addProfile()` is written:

```js
addProfile(profile: new (mapper: AutoMapper) => MappingProfile): AutoMapper {
    this._profileStorage.add(this, new profile(this));
    return this;
}
```

You can see that internally, `@nartc/automapper` will instantiate (`new profile()`) and pass in the `AutoMapper` instance to the Profile's constructor so that will be available for you inside of the `Profile's constructor`

For this piece of code in your `MerchantModule`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MerchantController } from './merchant.controller';
import { MerchantService } from './merchant.service';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { Merchant } from './entities/merchant.entity';
// import { MerchantProfile } from './profiles/merchant.profile';
// this is all you need which is to import the profile so TypeScript can execute it. Don't need `MerchantProfile` at all
import './profiles/merchant.profile';
import { AutoMapper, AutomapperModule } from 'nestjsx-automapper';

@Module({
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([Merchant])], // don't need to import AutoMapperModule again. MerchantProfile is not a Module so you can't import it
  exports: [TypeOrmModule],
  controllers: [MerchantController],
  providers: [MerchantService]
})
export class MerchantModule {}
```

In your `MerchantController`:

```js
@Controller('merchant')
export class MerchantController {

    constructor(
        private merchantService: MerchantService,
        @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: AutoMapper) { }

    @Get()
    public async findAll(): Promise<MerchantDto[]> {
        // make sure `this.merchantService.find()` returns an Array of 
        // Merchant instances. If not, please provide an extra param to map()
        // return this.mapper.mapArray(await this.merchantService.find(),MerchantDto);
        return this.mapper.mapArray(await this.merchantService.find(), MerchantDto, Merchant); // notice the 3rd parameter is the Source model.
    }
}
```

Please let me know if this works for you. If not, please create an issue in `nestjsx-automapper` repo and provide a reproducible repository, I'll take a look as soon as possible.

Comment: Thanks Chau! I will go through it and let you know. Another question: How should I deal with different DTO´s for one entity? E.g. I need to pass an entity without an "ID" attribute to the ORM when creating it but I need to have the ID attribute on update? Or the DTO for a GET Request would be again another one. I´ve seen a solution with different DTO classes (e.g. create-merchant.dto, update-merchant.dto) but I think that´s a bunch of boilerplate and code-duplication. Do you have a hint for me?

Comment: Your example works great Chau. Maybe it´s possible to add an example Projekt with a nest.js implementation to the documentation on https://automapper.netlify.app/docs/nest?

Comment: @MichaelFürst Let’s assume you have MerchantDto and you use MerchantDto for Create and Update. The only difference is the Id is nullable. What you can do in that case is to have a reverseMap()

Comment: Mapper.createMap(Merchant, MerchantDto).reverseMap().forPath(s => s.id, mapDefer(dest => dest.id ? mapFrom(d => d.id): ignore()))

Comment: Reach out to me on Discord if you'd want to discuss in details

Comment: I´d really like to.. :) Which Discord Channel?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with how the `AutoMappModule` works, but it looks like in your `MerchantModule` you import `AutoMapperModule` whereas you *should* be importing `AutoMapperModule.withMapper()`, similarly to how you did in the `AppModule`.