# NestJS with MongoDB and NestJsxAutomapper resulting in error 'cannot read property plugin of undefined'

Tags: node.js, dependency-injection, mapping, nestjs

I am working on an API with NestJS, and because I have DTO's I am using an AutoMapper (made by @nartc and/or nestjsx), I have tried to make my example as small as I could with the `Foo` example, because I use multiple files.

**This is my module:**

```
// foo.module.ts
import { Module } from "@nestjs/common";
import { MongooseModule } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

import { Foo, FooSchema } from "./foo.entity.ts";
import { FooController } from "./foo.controller.ts";
import { FooService } from "./foo.service.ts";
import { FooProfile } from "./foo.profile.ts";

@Module({
  imports: [
    MongooseModule.forFeature([
      {
        name: Foo.name,
        schema: FooSchema,
        collection: "foos",
      }
    ])
    // FooProfile <-- if I uncomment this, the program will give the error (shown at the bottom of this question)
  ],
  controllers: [FooController],
  providers: [FooProivder],
})
export class FooModule {}
```

---

**This is my entity:**

```
// foo.entity.ts
import { Schema, SchemaFactory, Prop } from "@nestjs/mongoose";
import { Document } from "mongoose";

@Schema()
export class Foo extends Document { // if I remove the `extends Document` it works just fine
  @Prop({ required: true })
  name: string;
  @Prop()
  age: number
}

export const FooSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Foo);
```

---

**This is my DTO:**

```
// foo.dto.ts
export class FooDTO {
  name: string;
}
```

---

**This is my controller:**

```
// foo.controller.ts
import { Controller, Get } from "@nestjs/common";
import { InjectMapper, AutoMapper } from "nestjsx-automapper";

import { Foo } from "./foo.entity";
import { FooService } from "./foo.service";
import { FooDTO } from "./dto/foo.dto";

@Controller("foos")
export class FooController {
  constructor(
    private readonly fooService: FooService
    @InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: AutoMapper
  ) {}

  @Get()
  async findAll() {
    const foos = await this.fooService.findAll();
    const mappedFoos = this.mapper.mapArray(foos, Foo, FooDTO);
    // ^^ this throws an error of the profile being undefined (duh)
    return mappedFoos;
  }
}
```

---

**This is my profile:**

```
// foo.profile.ts
import { Profile, ProfileBase, InjectMapper, AutoMapper } from "nestjsx-automapper";

import { Foo } from "./foo.entity";
import { FooDTO } from "./foo.dto";

@Profile()
export class FooProfile extends ProfileBase {
  constructor(@InjectMapper() private readonly mapper: AutoMapper) {
    // I've read somewhere that the `@InjectMapper() private readonly` part isn't needed,
    // but if I exclude that, it doesn't get the mapper instance. (mapper will be undefined)
    super();
    this.mapper.createMap(Foo, FooDTO);
  }
}
```

---

If I uncomment the line I highlighted in the module, it will result in the following error..

```sh
[Nest] 11360   - 2020-08-18 15:53:06   [ExceptionHandler] Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined +1ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'plugin' of undefined
    at Foo.Document.$__setSchema ($MYPATH\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2883:10)
    at new Document ($MYPATH\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:82:10)
    at new Foo($MYPATH\dist\foo\foo.entity.js:15:17)
```

I have also referred to [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461133/using-profiles-with-nestjsx-automapper-in-nest-js), but that doesn't work for me either. I have also combined that with the [documentation](https://github.com/nestjsx/automapper), but with no luck.. How would I get the AutoMapper to register my profiles?

**Update**

The error seems to originate from the foo entity, if I remove the `extends Document` and the `Schema()`, `Prop({ ... })` from the class it works fine, it seems like I have to inject mongoose or something?

Answer (score 1):

In your module, just import the path to the profile like below:

```
import 'relative/path/to/foo.profile';
```

By importing the path to file, `TypeScript` will include the file in the bundle and then the `@Profile()` decorator will be executed. When `@Profile()` is executed, `AutoMapperModule` keeps track of all the `Profiles` then when it's turn for NestJS to initialize `AutoMapperModule` (with `withMapper()` method), `AutoMapperModule` will automatically add the Profiles to the Mapper instance.

With that said, in your `FooProfile`'s constructor, you'll get `AutoMapper` instance that this profile will be added to

```
@Profile()
export class FooProfile extends ProfileBase {
   // this is the correct syntax. You would only need private/public access modifier
   // if you're not going to use this.mapper outside of the constructor
   // You DON'T need @InjectMapper() because that's Dependency Injection of NestJS. 
   // Profile isn't a part of NestJS's DI
   constructor(mapper: AutoMapper) {

   }
}
```

The above answer will solve your problems with `AutoMapper`. As far as your Mongoose problem, I would need a sample repro to tell for sure. And also, visit our Discord for this kind of question.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me.

**1. Updated all the absolute paths** for models, schemas, entities (is easy if you search for `from '/src` in your projects, and update all the routes to relative paths)

from:
`import { User } from 'src/app/auth/models/user/user.entity';`

to:
`import { User } from './../../auth/models/user/user.entity';`

**2. mongoose imports:**

from:
`import mongoose from 'mongoose';`

to:
`import * as mongoose from 'mongoose';`

**3. Remove validation pipe if you don't use it.** For some reason (I think i don't use them on the controller, I didn't investigate, I've removed from one controller the Validation Pipe) so If you have this try it:

from:

```
@Controller('someroute')
@UsePipes(new ValidationPipe())
export class SomeController {}
```

to:

```
@Controller('someroute')
export class SomeController {}
```

I hope my solution worked for you ^_^